Some android components are randomly being set alpha values on Android (React Native 0.73.8)
This is proving difficult to narrow down the exact cause unfortunately, but I'm getting very strange behaviour and I'm hoping someone has experienced something similar.
In my app I have a horizontal flat list, with some simple UI components inside:
const HorizontalContentThumbnailScroll = ({
    data
}: Props) => {
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        const {
            id,
            title,
        } = item

        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    width: THUMBNAIL_WIDTH,
                    marginRight: Metrics.horizontalScreenMargin,
                }}
            >
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300' }}
                        style={{
                            width: THUMBNAIL_WIDTH,
                            height: THUMBNAIL_WIDTH,
                        }}
                        resizeMode="cover"
                    />
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            ...Fonts.style.subHeading,
                            color: '#181C25',
                            paddingTop: Metrics.borderRadius.scale[2],
                            marginTop: 0,
                        }}
                        numberOfLines={3}
                    >
                        {title}
                    </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    const keyExtractor: FlatListProps['keyExtractor'] = ({ id }) => id

    return (
        <>
            <FlatList
                horizontal
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                {...{ data, renderItem, size, keyExtractor }}
            />
        </>
    )
}

Nothing here is setting any opacity styling at all, however seemingly randomly an opacity is being set on the image and text:

Using Flipper's Layout plugin I can see the native wrapping View is being given an alpha (opacity) less than 1:

The specific number seems to vary anywhere between 0 and 1. I also see the issue if I just include either the text or the image.
We are also (less frequently) getting this at other points in the component hierarchy with different components.
I have spent lots of time trying to recreate on an expo snack, but can't get the bug to display.
I can't see anything in our code that would be setting this alpha value, so I am wondering if it's a library. We use react-navigation (with native stacks) v6.x, react-native-screens v3.34.0 and react-native-gesture-handler v2.19.0.
If I move the horizontal scroll above these components, I can't recreate, but could of course be something else in the tree (or possibly because it takes longer to render further down the tree).
Has anyone experienced something similar and could help narrow down the cause? I am struggling to understand what could theoretically cause this.
